# Binary search for a double value in an integer array using builtin `Array.BinarySearch`

Tags: c#

What's the most succinct way of doing such a cross-type search? E.g.:

```
int[] a = new[] {1,4,8};
Array.BinarySearch(a, 3.5); // runtime error
```

The best solution I can find is:

```
Array.BinarySearch(new[] { 1, 4, 8 }, 3.5, new Comparer());

class Comparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        // return ((double)x).CompareTo((double)y); // runtime error! cannot convert boxed int to double
        return (Convert.ToDouble(x)).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(y));
    }
}
```

I don't like the above solution though it works, because:

1. boxing and unboxing is involved (I cannot use generic version `Array.BinarySearch<int>` here obviously)
2. `Convert.ToDouble` is unnecessarily inefficient
3. `Convert.ToDouble` also works for other types like string, so this would open doors for searches like `"3.5"`, etc. This is not as type safe as I would like.

I think the problem boils down to how to do int - double comparison dynamically, when both are boxed to `object`.

Of course, implementing a binary search speficially for this case is trivial, but my goal is to use builtin functions as much as possible.

If I would extend the built in function, I probably would provide such a function:

```
int BinarySearch<T, TTarget>(T[] array, TTarget target, Func<T, TTarget> convert);
```

I would state that it's the user's responsibility to make sure `convert` is a monotonically increasing function. Then I would use it like:

```
Array.BinarySearch(new[] {1,4,8}, 3.5, i => (double)i);
```

Comment: They're only being boxed at all because you're implementing the non-generic comparer. Fundamentally, I'd suggest just not doing this: do a binary search for `3` or `4` and go from there.

Comment: Oh @JonSkeet this is smart. Yeah thanks!

Comment: Why are you searching for a non-integral double in an integer array? You can trivially assume it won't be found, otherwise convert it before searching? PS You can test for fraction with `(d % 1.0) != 0.0`

Comment: @NetMage, for example, I want to find the closest integer to the target double without a linear scan.

Comment: I guess you can use the negative answer to compute the above/below indexes and then decide which is closest? In that case, I would still suggest converting to `int` before searching.